# Is there some way to not show a warning for non snake case identifiers?

Tags: rust

I'm writing my first tests in Rust and I find this:

> warning: function `testCall` should have a snake case name such as
>   `test_call`, #[warn(non_snake_case)] on by default

after searching, I found [this style guide](https://aturon.github.io/style/naming.html).

I understand it is a convention, but is there some way to not show this warning?

Comment: I'm not a fan of using underscores. Think it comes from having trouble printing them on a old dot-matrix printer many years ago.

Comment: Is there any way I can enforce this warning ignorance on crate names as well?

Answer (score 95, accepted):

You can use the `allow` attribute as such:

```
#[allow(non_snake_case)]
fn nonSnakeCase() {}
```

More on attributes [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/attributes.html).

Comment: I found this way thanks to its response "rustc -A non_snake_case main.rs"

Comment: You should also be able to use `#![allow(non_snake_case)]` to apply the attribute to the entire file

Comment: Doesn't work for me. It's still warning.

Comment: @Alper
if you have `use` statements then add this line after the `use` block

#[allow(non_snake_case)]

Comment: It's fine, I was adding it at the usage site and not at the declaration site. (It was late.)